# Rails 6 ActiveJob undefined constant ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq, rails-activejob, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm upgrading an app to Rails 6 and after fixing all breaking changes I'm now facing an error when sending emails from background jobs.

I use Sidekiq through ActiveJob and I believe I've added the necessary config changes:

```
# config/application.rb

...

config.load_defaults 6.0
```

```
# config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_6_0.rb

...

Rails.application.config.action_mailer.delivery_job = "ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob"
```

I'm sending emails using `deliver_later`, like: `UserMailer.notify(user).deliver_later`

**One important aspect is that the emails ARE being delivered even though I'm getting the error**

Error message:

```
NameError:
uninitialized constant ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob
Did you mean?  ActionMailer::DeliveryJob
```

According to Rollbar the context of the error is `ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper`

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob` is new for rails 6, previously it was called `ActionMailer::DeliveryJob` (and is still present in rails 6 but with deprecation warning for smoother migration)

Looks like you have a situation when jobs from new rails ended up in a sidekiq worker that is still running previous version.
Since emails are actually being delivered - most probably you have workers with both rails versions at the same time. Some workers generate the error and job is retried until it is picked by a worker that finally delivers.

To prevent the error it's better to deploy with `action_mailer.delivery_job = "ActionMailer::DeliveryJob"`, make sure all workers are upgraded (=restarted with new code) and only then remove deprecation warning by switching to `MailDeliveryJob`.

Comment: You're correct! To fix it I deployed the new code and used `ps -aux` to look for old Sidekiq processes, after finding and killing an old process everything started to work without errors. Thanks!